# Unable to retrieve List Items from Graph using Postman

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to retrieve a list of all the items for a Sharepoint REST through Postman, employing the Graph API. When I use the Graph Explorer website, I am able to get all the fields for a specific item through

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}/items/{itemID}
```

but when I try replicating the same in Postman, it fails and just gives me the following:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites({siteID})/lists({listID})/items",
  "value": []
}
```

The only header in my GET request is the Authorization Bearer Token from Azure AD, which seems to be working fine, as I get the list information in Postman with the same URL excluding the `/items` part:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteID}/lists/{listID}
```

Any help on this front would be appreciated - I have used [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@anoopt/access-sharepoint-data-using-postman-eec5965400f2) to guide me. It's all worked till the final part which is getting the data in Postman instead of Microsoft Graph Explorer

Comment: Is this a List or a Drive? Could you try `/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/root/children`?

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur, how's going ? has your issue be solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same issue and after I grant permission , this issue solved . Try steps below : 
1. Go to Azure AD , select the application that you used for obtaining access token : 
[image]

**Note : After you added the permission , pls click the "Grant permission for your tenant " button to finish the grant permission process** .

This is the result before I grant the permission :
[image]

After I grant the permission and get a **new token** to call the API, I can get the items data :
[image]

Hope it helps .